# Materialize dropdown not working in navbar (React)

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, materialize

I am trying to use a dropdown menu in the navbar, although i am using react and some thing need to be done differently which i did. I still have no idea whats wrong. this is the code i am using, does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong?

```
import M from 'materialize-css';
const Navbar = ({ lang: { language, loading }, getLang }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    getLang(0);
    let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    let options = {
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      hover: true,
      belowOrigin: true
    };
    M.Dropdown.init(dropdowns, options);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  if (!language || loading) {
    return <Preloader />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className='blue darken-2'>
        <div className='nav-wrapper'>
          <Link to='/' className='brand-logo' style={{ marginLeft: '1%' }}>
            SwimTechNL
          </Link>
          <ul
            id='nav-mobile'
            className='right hide-on-med-and-down'
            style={{ marginRight: '1%' }}
          >
            <li>
              <Link to='/about'>{language.Navbar.about}</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className='dropdown-trigger' href='#!' data-target='dropdown1'>
                Dropdown<i class='material-icons right'>arrow_drop_down</i>
              </a>
              <ul id='dropdown1' className='dropdown-content'>
                <li>
                  <a href='#!'>one</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href='#!'>two</a>
                </li>
                <li className='divider'></li>
                <li>
                  <a href='#!'>three</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are *instantiating* a Dropdown *object* but not calling any methods on it.

These can be found here https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html#methods in their documentation.

What you can probably do is call the `open()` and `close()` methods on your *anchor tag* `<a>` for dropdown like following:

```
<a
   id="FirstDropDown"
   className="dropdown-trigger"
   href="#!"
   data-target="dropdown1"
   onMouseEnter={e => M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target).open()}
   onMouseLeave={e => M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target).close()}
   >
   Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
</a>
```

Though this might close the drop down as soon as you move over to the drop down list for which you can either move these functions to the `<li>` tag and then refer the element accordingly or use different [Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events) depending on your requirements.

**UPDATE**
So it seems that it works perfectly well by just opening the dropdown and the rest is handled by the library itself. So the following code should do the job:

```
<a
   id="FirstDropDown"
   className="dropdown-trigger"
   href="#!"
   data-target="dropdown1"
   onMouseEnter={e => {
   const inst = M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target);
   inst && inst.open();
   }}
   >
   Dropdown <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
 </a>
```

If it doesn't you can have a similar function call to `close()` method.

Here's the complete code for it.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css";

const Navbar = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-trigger");
    let options = {
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      hover: true,
      belowOrigin: true
    };
    M.Dropdown.init(dropdowns, options);

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="blue darken-2">
        <div className="nav-wrapper">
          <a className="brand-logo" style={{ marginLeft: "1%" }}>
            SwimTechNL
          </a>
          <ul
            id="nav-mobile"
            className="right hide-on-med-and-down"
            style={{ marginRight: "1%" }}
          >
            <li>
              <a>About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                id="FirstDropDown"
                className="dropdown-trigger"
                href="#!"
                data-target="dropdown1"
                onMouseEnter={e => {
                  const inst = M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target);
                  inst && inst.open();
                }}
              >
                Dropdown <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
              </a>
              <ul
                style={{ marginLeft: "500px", display: "none" }}
                id="dropdown1"
                className="dropdown-content"

              >
                <li style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
                  <a href="#!">one</a>
                </li>
                <li style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                  <a href="#!">two</a>
                </li>
                <li className="divider"></li>
                <li style={{ backgroundColor: "purple" }}>
                  <a href="#!">three</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: @istvan kolkert Do let me know if the basic solution helps then if you need any help in changing the behaviour please feel free to comment here. Thanks.

Comment: If i use this i just get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined when i hover my mouse over the dropdown

Comment: Yes that might happen possibly due to any of the two reasons either it is that since useEffect runs after the render therefore it is still undefined for which you can add an array of DropDowns using useState or simply console.log e.target and see if you are able to capture the element.

Comment: console.log just logs the element you described above, but this isn't the problem right? And what do you mean with an array of dropdowns?

Comment: try these instead `onMouseEnter={e => M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target) && M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target).open()}` `onMouseLeave={e => M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target) && M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target).close()}`

Comment: Just add these statements to short-circuit the function call. More clean: `onMouseEnter={e => { const inst = M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target);
                  inst && inst.open(); }}` `onMouseLeave={e => {
                  const inst = M.Dropdown.getInstance(e.target);
                  inst && inst.close();
                }}`

Comment: Sadly even with the close method i still get no response at all or errors

Comment: Try the updated code replace your `<a>` tag with the second code I have written.

Comment: Nope, not doing anything at all

Comment: You can create a sandbox example for it or just share your detailed code here for the concerned files.

Comment: Well for the example its just what is in my original question only i replaced the a tag with your example, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Nah! Just the same what you did. Let me post the code myself.

Comment: The code that I have posted works fine for me. Its from your example.

Comment: If this doesn't work please feel free to comment what is it that is not working on your side, are there some errors or is it just that the drop-down is simply not opening.

Comment: I copied your example but it still doesn't work for some reason maybe i am missing something in my index.html? And there are no errors its just the drop-down not opening

Comment: O wait i got it to work if i use your example without any other stuff, i will try to convert your example to mine, like using redux and more, i will let you know when it stops working

Comment: Ok great. Let me know if you need any further help. And if you are satisfied you can accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Alright i sorta found the problem, for some reason the preloader i use is breaking the dropdown...: `if (!language || loading) {
    return <Preloader />;
  }`

Comment: Thanks for your help btw, but do you have any idea why this is breaking the dropdown?

Comment: Try removing the `[] empty array` from useEffect()

Comment: The reason maybe that on the first render only `<Preloader />` maybe loading and when eventually the props change and dropdown renders the useEffect() won't run.

Comment: The empty array is there to prevent it running constantly, i tried moving the stuff for the dropdown to a seperate function which runs after the preloader is gone, but still the same result

Comment: Wouldn't know about your whole code. Try to debug see whether the dropdowns even get rendered or not. If you are unable to figure out anything you can post it as a separate question with its own details.

Comment: Will do! Thank you